# Accessing Global Pause Hotkey in Ruby for Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, global

I made a spotify player for the amazon echo, it worked great on OSX. I open spotify using appscript and am able to pause and play spotify by manipulating the application in appscipt. However this will not work when using Windows, since applescript is OSX specific.

I know that win32ole paired with AHK is an option, but I can't seem to get it to work. Does anyone have a piece of Ruby code that replicates what the keyboard does when the {PAUSE} button is hit on windows. It is a global pause that will pause any media player currently playing, whether it is in fore or background.

I even got SendKeys to work with win32ole and was able to correctly send CAPSLOCK, and set my keys to CAPSLOCK, but PAUSE didn't work, nor did STOP. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266279(v=vs.60).aspx).

Thank you kind friends!

Comment: Did you solve it? Could you share your code, espacially how you got SendKeys to work with win32ole!Thanks

Comment: s=WIN32OLE.new("WScript.Shell")
s.SendKeys("{CAPSLOCK}")
this should help you get sendkeys working have fun.